# autotools 向けのコーディング規約はありますか？

Tags: makefile

良い autotools 向けのコーディング規約があったら教えてください。

Comment: `configure.ac`(autoconf)や`Makefile.am`(automake)の記述に関する規約という意味でしょうか？

Comment: はい。ただ Makefile の記述に関するものも含むとなお良いです。